# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to get back info from Bing's auto suggest but getting the above error. I assume it's something to do with the formatting but when I try adding `&format=json` I get a 403 error. I've read related q's which speak of adding `application/javascript` to the header but how would I do this in the below example? I'm pretty new to AJAX.

```
$().ready(function(){ 
var url = 'http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=test&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      alert(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't add anything to the header, as the header is created/sent by bing.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/9R94S/) ya go. You were missing the `JsonType=callback` in the url.

```
var url = 'http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=test&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?'; 
$.getJSON(url, function( data ){ alert( data ) } );
```

This is actually Bing specific and you can find documentation on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx).

Comment: ah.. thanks, but what does that property do? Would you recommend a nice Jquery reference guide? I'd rather not have to repeat similar silly mistakes.

Comment: @user596186 Sorry, looks like I completely misunderstood the problem :)

Comment: User, the JsonType is bing specific and is unrelated to jQuery. I have added a link which should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into $.ajax implementation, the "accept" property specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is add a different content type in your request. To do this, you may have to use jQuery's `$.ajax` function instead of your `getJSON` function. You can make the former behave identically, but you have more control over the settings you provide.

You're after something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=test&callback=?,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/javascript',
  success: function() {alert(data);}
});
```

Comment: Gives back the same error `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.`